# Does PHP have a FIPS mode? Does it provide an option/flag to choose FIPS or non-FIPS?

Tags: php, cryptography, fips

I wanted to know if PHP has a FIPS mode, something similar to what MySQL or Nodejs has.

For MySQL, please refer to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ssl_fips_mode), it got introduced in MySQL 8.0

For Nodejs please refer to: [Improved control over FIPS mode](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5181) which introduced --enable-fips and --force-fips flags in Nodejs 6.0.0

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate. I am asking if PHP has an option/flag to enable FIPS mode? Not asking if PHP's password_hash is FIPS complaint. Please review again.

Comment: I agree, not a dup, but it's close. It does answer your question, effectively.

Comment: Man this would be a great question to have an answer to. I mean the answer is obviously no, but ... how can you use PHP with FIPS? Guess we'll never know because this is a duplicate of some question about password hashing.

Comment: Yeah this is not a duplicate. Like what happens on a fips server when you run the sha functions?